# ASP.NET User Permissions through Policies

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, roles, user-management

I am in the process of creating a web application that allows users to add, edit and share content and need some help understanding how to set permissions for the content. Here is the setup:

1. There are multiple users.
2. Each user can add content (an object created from a class called Project)
3. For each project, the user who added it can set the permissions that restrict what other users can do. To keep it simple, let's say there are two permissions: view and edit.

Item 1 is very straight forward and ASP.NET provides user login and identities. 2 is also simple. What about 3? What is the best way to store and enforce these permissions? One way to do this with code is to have a list in the project class that stores user IDs and the associated permissions.

But are there built in features in ASP.NET to facilitate 3? I am familiar with roles, but I don't think that they would work because each project might give users different permissions. I have also been reading about policies, but I don't understand it well enough yet to figure out if I could use it to handle the permissions.

Please let me know if existing ASP.NET features can be used to manage the permissions. If not, is the approach that involves storing the User IDs and permissions the way to go or is there a better (safer) way to do it?

Comment: look at the identity framwork,  you can add capabilities to a users identity, via roles.  and it is a users capabilities that determines what they can do.  You can create filters, to decorate your controllers, which check hat a user has the correct capability for the action.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using?  core or 4.x?

Comment: Core. But the application is in its infancy, so I'd be open to switching if Core does not have the functionalities.